# How to move to a specific navtab through header function of php

Tags: php, html, function, header

Is there any way that I can move to a specific navtab through header function after submit(page reload) through header function.

like 
in teacher.php here is the div of navtab somewhere in the tab-content.

```
<div id=" change-password " class="tab-pane fade">

</div>
```

I want to move like in teacher.php in id="change-password" tab from header function.
i.e

```
if(isset($_POST['value'])
{
  header("location:teacher.php[address of change-password tab]");
}
```

So, the page should reload with a change password tab not with default active tab.

Comment: Tab should be activated on a client-side

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a GET variable when redirecting:

```
header("location:teacher.php?password_changed");
```

Then you can check existence of this variable and event. display the specified tab:

```
if (isset($_GET['password_changed']) {
    $class = "active";
} else {
    $class = "";
}
?>

<div id="change-password" class="tab-pane fade <?php echo $class; ?>">
```

Of course, the classname depends on css framework you are using. If you're not using any framework for the tabs, you need to write the active-tab logic yourself.

---

If you need multiple tabs, you could use the GET variable's content (not just its existence):

```
header("location:teacher.php?tab=password_changed");
// or
header("location:teacher.php?tab=some_other_tab");
```

When rendering HTML, it'd be simpler to use inline PHP statements:

```
<div class="<?php echo $_GET['tab'] === 'password_changed' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
<!-- or -->
<div class="<?php echo $_GET['tab'] === 'some_other_tab' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
```

Comment: is this can work with multiple navtabs?
I mean all tabs depending on data coming from database.

how could i cater that case.

Answer (score 0):

This ultimately depends on how you are implementing your tabbed content in your theme layer.

Several theming frameworks and javascript plugins support navigating directly to a page and bringing a particular tab of content into focus using the ID of the tab and some javascript.  In all cases, you can use some javascript or jQuery to bring the desired tab into focus on page load/document ready.

Alternatively, to avoid depending on javascript on page load, you can serve the page with the css class that javascript would otherwise apply, you can use a query parameter passed via GET or POST (as suggested by @martin-heralecky), or use cookie or local_storage if your password reset/login process utilizes AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

Short way;

```
header("location:teacher.php?tab=password_changed");

<div id="change-password" class="tab-pane fade <?php echo (($_GET['tab']!='password_changed')?:'activeClass'); ?>"></div>
```